# Divide a List of objects into sub-lists without creating additional objects

Tags: c#

I'm trying to shake off the coding rust after a hiatus, and so have taken on the task creating a simple card game. I know I'm making a rookie mistake but I can't seem to find the solution.

I am trying to implement a few conceptual shuffle methods, one of which involves the deck being emptied into a number of separate stacks then recompiled into a deck again.

My `deck` is a standard `List<T>` of `Cards`. My goal is to take a the top card `[0]` from the `'temp_deck'` and add it to pile/stack `x`, thus removing it from the top of the `temp_deck`. Then add the top card to pile/stack `y`, then `z`, until `temp_deck` has no more cards. Then I can proceed to manipulate the 3 piles and add them back to the final deck.

My issue is that for some reason, it is adding every `card` in `temp_deck` to each pile, so each stack `x, y, z` has 52 cards. How can I resolve this so that I am dividing my list between these piles instead of multiplying it?

Here is my current (nth) attempt at dividing the list:

```
    public void Shuffle_b(Deck deck)
    {
        Deck temp_deck = deck;
        Deck x = new Deck();
        x.Cards.Clear();
        Deck y = x;
        Deck z = y;

        while (temp_deck.Cards.Count !=0)
        {

            if (temp_deck.Cards.Count != 0)
            {
                x.Cards.Add(temp_deck.Cards[0]);
                temp_deck.Cards.Remove(temp_deck.Cards[0]);

                if (temp_deck.Cards.Count != 0)
                {
                    y.Cards.Add(temp_deck.Cards[0]);
                    temp_deck.Cards.Remove(temp_deck.Cards[0]);

                    if (temp_deck.Cards.Count != 0)
                    {
                        z.Cards.Add(temp_deck.Cards[0]);
                        temp_deck.Cards.Remove(temp_deck.Cards[0]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
   }
```

Comment: Unrelated, your top `if` is unnecessary.  You've already tested this with your while loop.  The consistency is great, but if you want that, do it with a `MoveCard` function, which will have the added benefit of removing the nesting.  Also, the *only* (effectively) non-temporary variable in your function is `temp_deck`.  You should rethink that name within the function.

Comment: You have declared 4 new decks in your code, but `x`, `y`, and `z` are all referring to the same memory location, and `temp_deck` is pointing to the same memory location as `deck`, so you really only have 2 decks in total, with 5 references between them.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation guys! That cleared up a big headache for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are setting decks y and z to point to the same object x that you created once. Change the lines:

```
    Deck y = x;
    Deck z = y;
```

to

```
    Deck y = new Deck();
    Deck z = new Deck();
```

You should understand that x, y, z are references to an object, and when you assign y = x, you are pointing y to the same thing that x was pointing to.

Comment: Which incidentally speaks to my comment's point about `temp_deck` pointing at the only locally-*permanent* collection this function deals with.

Answer (score 2):

When you assign an object to another one, you are not creating a copy of the other object, but rather you are saying "let my new object point to the same location as this existing object". So in your code you have declared 4 new decks, but `x`, `y`, and `z` are all referring to the same memory location, and `temp_deck` is pointing to the same memory location as `deck`, so you really only have 2 decks in total, with 5 references between them.

Instead, if you want a brand new object, you have to use the `new` keyword (or call some method that returns a new object).

Here's an example that may help illustrate this. We start out by creating 3 new decks, then we loop through each item in the deck that was passed to the method. Inside the loop, we create a new deck that points to the memory location of one of the three we created earlier (chosen by the value of 'i' index inside the loop).

Basically we take the index (the value of `i`), add one (since it's zero-based) and get the remainder after dividing it by 3. If the remainder is 1, then use deck `x`, if the remainder is 2, use deck `y`, and otherwise (remainder of 0) use deck `z`.

At the end of each iteration, the `addTo` deck is gone - it was only a temporary pointer inside the loop. And at the very end, our three decks are equally filled with items from the deck that was passed in:

```
public static void Shuffle_b(Deck deck)
{
    if (deck == null || !deck.Cards.Any()) return;

    Deck x = new Deck();
    Deck y = new Deck();
    Deck z = new Deck();

    for (int i = 0; i < deck.Cards.Count; i++)
    {
        // Add one to i, then get the remainder from dividing it by 3
        int deckNo = (i + 1) % 3;

        // If the remainder is 1, use deck x; if it's 2 use deck y; else use deck z
        Deck addTo = (deckNo == 1) ? x : (deckNo == 2) ? y : z;

        // Add the card to our selected deck
        addTo.Cards.Add(deck.Cards[i]);
    }

    // Now x contains the cards from 'deck' at indexes: 0, 3, 6, 9, etc...
    // And y contains the cards from 'deck' at indexes: 1, 4, 7, 10, etc...
    // And z contains the cards from 'deck' at indexes: 2, 5, 8, 11, etc..
}
```

Comment: This is an excellent approach to the problem. I had something similar to this as a WIP, but simplified to attempt to analyse my mistake.

Answer (score -2):

What you're looking after is [yield](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/yield) keyword

```
if (match condition)
 yield return element
```

Structuring calls in a way that you enter in the right if, will yield the results you need without creating further objects.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why the OP is creating multiple decks to shuffle another deck, or if he is shuffling the deck. I'm equally unsure how this would help him. Clearly putting a yield into his existing code without further changes won't. Can you elaborate?

Comment: There's no answer here. Just a vague pointer at an iterator approach which the OP isn't taking

Comment: @zzxyz because you don't understand it. Just use yield to avoid creating new objects.